# Is auto layout system different for NSTableCellViews?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have created a subclass of `NStextField` that expands and shrinks to accomodate changes in the text. Here is the code:

```
- (NSSize)sizeToFitContent
{
    NSRect frame = [self frame];
    CGFloat width = frame.size.width;
    frame.size.height = CGFLOAT_MAX;
    CGFloat height = [self.cell cellSizeForBounds: frame].height;
    return NSMakeSize(width, height);
}

- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [super textDidChange:aNotification];
    [(NSCell *)self.cell title];
    NSSize newSize = [self sizeToFitContent];
    if (newSize.height != self.frame.size.height) {
        [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    }
}

- (NSSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    if ( ![self.cell wraps] ) {
        return [super intrinsicContentSize];
    }
    return [self sizeToFitContent];
}
```

I have verified that the control does what I want it to do in several projects. Recently I tried to place the control inside a `NSTableCellView` and it stopped working. If I set the stringValue of the control programmatically the control changes its size correctly. However if I type or delete text from the control it does not resize when a new line is needed.
I can't really figure out why the control behaves differently in these two situations?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to implement

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView heightOfRow:(NSInteger)row
```

in your [NSTableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: mm, i already have that implemented well in my project, but it doesn't work for editing. in fact, i implemented textDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification which does get the notifications as you type in the cell, and it sends noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged: to my table view, but no resizing joy results. calling setNeedsDisplay on the table view doesn't force it to redraw, either. not sure it's possible with nstextfieldcell...